# Like button and og:type=article

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, photos

We've been trying to get the Like button to work with og:type = article since we are sharing photos.  So far, if we use article, the post appears on the wall but the counts do not increment correctly.

If the user clicks like, before the comment box appears, the like count out at

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select+url,total_count,like_count,comment_count,share_count,click_count+from+link_stat+where+url=%27http%3A%2F%2Ftestenv.snap2twitter.com%2Fphotos%2F1829074%27&format=json

shows the like count incremented by one.

If the user enters a comment, however, the count is reset to 0!

If we change the og:type to "website", the counts work but ONLY if a user enters a comment (reverse problem).  If they don't, nothing appears on the Wall or in the timeline but the Activity log shows the user Shared a link.

Our headers (for og:type=article) are:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# article: http://ogp.me/ns/article#">
```

The og:tags are

```
<meta content="Love My Yellow Ferarri - Snap MyLife" property="og:title">
<meta content="Snap MyLife" property="og:site_name">
<meta content="article" property="og:type">
<meta content="<my app id>" property="fb:app_id">
<meta content="http://files-testenv.mobicious.com/files/2012/02/28/164634/1829078/new_large.jpg" property="og:image">
<meta content="http://testenv.snap2twitter.com/photos/1829078" property="og:url">
<meta content="Love My Yellow Ferarri" property="og:description">
```

Anyone have any ideas?  Does anyone have the Like button working correctly with og:type=article?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

hope this help you

News things about [og:type = article](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/news/)

[Live Example](http://www.stanforddaily.com/2011/01/24/card-trounces-trojans/)

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't.  You're not saying I need to specify all those new tags are you?